# Record sounds from an external device using a double ended audio jack

Tags: audio-output

I am using my computer, another device, and a double ended audio jack. I want to know if it is possible to record the audio output of the other device using some kind of software and the double ended audio jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/) to record sound coming in from any audio input hardware. Just connect the device playing the audio to the recorder's line in port and tell Audacity to use that device to record from.